# Can a TFLite float 16 model be converted to uint 8?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, quantization

I have found a pretrained TFLite model quantized to float 16. However, due to hardware constraints, I need a model that is quantized to uint 8. Can I convert a model from one type of quantization to another?

I cannot find any way to load a tflite model into the TFLiteConverter class, only SavedModels or Keras models can be loaded from what I can see.